# Producer Consumer scenario implementation in Java

Tags: java

Please suggest improvements in the following java program I've written for producer-consumer scenario. The program seems to be working fine. Does it suffer from possible deadlock scenarios? How better I could have done this? Since I am using Stack read/write (push/pop) already been synchronized? What if they do not?

```
import java.util.Stack;

import logger.CustomLogger;

public class TestProducerConsumer {

    private Stack<Integer> buffer;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    public int count;

    public TestProducerConsumer(){

        buffer = new Stack<Integer>();
        count = 0;
    }

    public Stack<Integer> getBuffer(){
        return buffer;
    }

    public void addToBuffer(Integer i) throws StackException{

        if(buffer.size() < MAX_SIZE){
            buffer.push(i);
            CustomLogger.logger.info("pushed "+i);
        }else
            throw new StackException("Stack Over Flow");
    }

    public Integer removeFromBuffer() throws StackException{

        if(buffer.size() == 0)
            throw new StackException("Buffer Empty");
        else 
            return buffer.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestProducerConsumer pd = new TestProducerConsumer();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(pd);
        Producer p2 = new Producer(pd);
        Producer p3 = new Producer(pd);

        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(pd);
        Consumer c2 = new Consumer(pd);
        Consumer c3 = new Consumer(pd);
        Consumer c4 = new Consumer(pd);
        Consumer c5 = new Consumer(pd);

        Thread tp1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread tp2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread tp3 = new Thread(p3);

        Thread tc1 = new Thread(c1);
        Thread tc2 = new Thread(c2);
        Thread tc3 = new Thread(c3);
        Thread tc4 = new Thread(c4);
        Thread tc5 = new Thread(c5);

        tp1.start();
        tc1.start();
        tc2.start();
        tc3.start();
        tc4.start();
        tc5.start();
        tp2.start();
        tp3.start();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable{

    private TestProducerConsumer pc;

    public Producer(){

    }
    public Producer(TestProducerConsumer pc){
        this.pc = pc;
    }

    public void run() {

        Stack<Integer> buf = pc.getBuffer();


        while(true){    
            synchronized(pc){               
                if(buf.size() < pc.MAX_SIZE){
                    try {
                        pc.addToBuffer(new Integer((pc.count)++));
                        if(buf.size() == 1){
                            CustomLogger.logger.info("Wake up consumer");
                            pc.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (StackException e) {
                        CustomLogger.logger.info(e.getError());
                        break;              
                    }
                } else{
                    try {
                        CustomLogger.logger.info("Producer sleeping");
                        pc.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

      }
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private TestProducerConsumer pc;

    public Consumer(TestProducerConsumer pc){
        this.pc = pc;
    }

    public void run(){

        Stack<Integer> buf = pc.getBuffer();
        int i;

        while(true){

            synchronized(pc){

                if(buf.size() == 0){

                    try {
                        CustomLogger.logger.info("Consumer Sleeping");
                        pc.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else
                {
                    try {
                        i = pc.removeFromBuffer();
                        CustomLogger.logger.info("poped "+i);

                        if(buf.size() == 0){
                            CustomLogger.logger.info("Wake up Producer");
                            pc.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (StackException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getError());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class StackException extends Exception{
    private String reason;

    public StackException(){
        super();
    }
    public StackException(String reason){
        super(reason);
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getError(){
        return reason;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a Stack for Producer/Consumer. I would just use a Queue or even better an ExecutorService.

Comment: Let me discourage you from having a `getBuffer()` method which directly exposes the underlying data structure. If you want to control how the collection is modified through your own `addToBuffer` and `removeFromBuffer` methods, then you're completely sacrificing any guarantee of that by exposing `buffer` directly (allowing some outside code to call `getBuffer().push`).

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a queue as they are designed for this sort of thing. The code is much shorter.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class TestProducerConsumer {
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 10;
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> tasks = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(MAX_SIZE);
    public final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    public final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    public static final int POISON_VALUE = -1;

    public void addToBuffer(Integer i) {
        try {
            tasks.put(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    public Integer removeFromBuffer() {
        try {
            return tasks.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TestProducerConsumer pd = new TestProducerConsumer();
        pd.new Producer();
        pd.new Producer();
        pd.new Producer();

        pd.new Consumer();
        pd.new Consumer();
        pd.new Consumer();
        pd.new Consumer();
        pd.new Consumer();
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable {
        public Producer() {
            executor.execute(this);
        }

        public void run() {
            while (count.get() >= 0) {
                addToBuffer(count.getAndIncrement());
            }
            addToBuffer(TestProducerConsumer.POISON_VALUE);
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {
        public Consumer() {
            executor.execute(this);
        }

        public void run() {
            Integer num;
            while ((num = removeFromBuffer()) != TestProducerConsumer.POISON_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("popped " + num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation does not rise an exception if the queue is full, it blocks the request! (same for removeFromBuffer for an empty queue). -- I don't know if this is an improvement or not - any way it should be mentioned, that this implementation does not behave like the "original" one.

Comment: It uses a queue instead of a Stack so it processes work in the order it is created.  That is a more important difference.  The StackException would only be thrown when there is a thread safety issue which won't happen for a BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is not thread-safe.

For example, if two threads invoke `addToBuffer(Integer i)` at the *same* time, both can pass the `if(buffer.size() < MAX_SIZE)` check before one of them puts an item into the stack, therefore the stack can have more items than MAX_SIZE!

The same is for `removeFromBuffer()`, and combinations of add and remove will have there own unexpected behaviour.

---

In general instead of implementing it by your own have a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package

> Queues
>
> The java.util.concurrent ConcurrentLinkedQueue class supplies an efficient scalable thread-safe non-blocking FIFO queue. Five implementations in java.util.concurrent support the extended BlockingQueue interface, that defines blocking versions of put and take: LinkedBlockingQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, SynchronousQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, and DelayQueue. The different classes cover the most common usage contexts for producer-consumer, messaging, parallel tasking, and related concurrent designs. The BlockingDeque interface extends BlockingQueue to support both FIFO and LIFO (stack-based) operations. Class LinkedBlockingDeque provides an implementation.