# Using the wildcard when importing packages

Tags: java, beginner

I am learning java and browsing posts on CodeReview and StackOverflow.

In my text **Introduction to Java Programming- Y Daniel Liang** it states:

> The wildcard import imports all classes in a package by using ...
>   The information for the classes in an imported package is not read in
>   at compile time or runtime unless the class is used in the program.
>   The import statement simply tells the compiler where to locate the
>   classes. There is no performance difference between a specific and a
>   wildcard import declaration.

These are two examples:

[This question:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25424/how-ho-make-this-code-more-simple-and-optimized)  **(1)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
```

[This answer:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2540/29649) **(2)**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
```

Could these be written as:

**(1)**

```
import java.util.*
import javafx.beans.*
import javafx.collections.*
import javafx.geometry.*
import javafx.scene.*
import javafx.stage.*
```

and

**(2)**

```
import java. util.*
```

**Are there exceptions to using the wildcard for importing?

What is considered the best practice when specifying imports?**

*I am not sure if this is best posted on code review or stackoverflow*

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this question would be better suited for Programmers.

Answer (score 7):

First, let's acknowledge that this is a subjective question.  However, in my opinion, it is constructive enough to be on topic for this site.

I would treat the standard Java library differently than your own packages or third-party packages.  Everyone recognizes classes from the standard Java library, such as `BufferedReader`, `PrintWriter`, and `IOException`.  There is therefore no value in importing those individually; it just clutters the code.  Everyone who has worked with Java will know that those classes belong to the `java.io` package, unambiguously.  Anyone who writes classes whose names conflict with those well known classes will be soundly beaten up, so name conflicts with `java.` classes just don't happen in practice.

With third-party libraries, it makes sense to import more specifically.  Programmers encountering those classes could use some help to figure out which packages they belong to.  Name clashes *could* happen.  That said, star imports for third-party libraries would be a judgement call.  I would suggest importing individual classes up to some number of classes (around 4) per package; beyond that, a star import might be sensible.  I would try to avoid star-importing more than one such package, though, to mitigate against the documentation-searching and name clash concerns.  (If you feel the urge to star-import multiple packages, your class is probably doing too much anyway and should be split up.)

With code that you have written yourself for the same or a closely related project, go ahead and star-import related packages, judiciously.  If you're working with the source code, you'll be familiar with the related code in neighbouring packages anyway.  If it fails to compile because of a name clash, you can fix it yourself.

Comment: By all means, feel free to [wait](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/772/9357) for responses to roll in before you decide to accept.

Comment: The problem with this is that you assume the programmer writes imports themselves (since AFAIK no IDE can do what you describe). I guess that without the possibility to do selective star imports automaticaly, the arguments against stars imports IMHO prevail. The times when I knew what class is where are long gone and I don't care, that's Eclipse's job.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to use star imports, because they can lead to ambiguities. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/147461/660143

There is no consensus about whether star import are good or bad. My IDE organizes the imports for me, so I don't care if there are a lot of import statements in my code. But that's my personal opinion.

Comment: There is no consensus about whether star import are good or bad. My IDE organizes the imports for me, so I don't care if there are a lot of import statements in my code. But that's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You have a misconception

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
```

can't be write like

```
import java.util.*;
```

`*`(wildcard) only imports all the classes from the package, but it doesn't import all the packages inside the package, if that was possible then we can just say

```
import java.*;
```

But that's not right.

Comment: that is precisely why I wrote this question.. +1 ty

Comment: @YvetteColomb its not clear that's what you're asking. I needed to see Anirban's comment to understand this constraint